# Laravel - How to create user roles based on companies using Laravel Permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am using Laravel-Permission and Laravel-8 for User Role-Based Access Level:

I have these tables:

User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Hash;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'other_name',
        'last_name',
        'company_id', 
        'updated_at',
        'created_at',
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\Company');
    }
}
```

Company Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Organization;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Company extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'companies';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                'id',
                'company_name',
                'address1',
                'address2',
                'org_head',
                'created_by',
                'created_at',
                'updated_by',
                'updated_at',
                'is_active'
            ];
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
 }
```

Each user is attached at least to a company. Apart from the SuperAdmin Role, I want Roles to belong to companies.
That is, each company should create it's own Roles.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly my question. I hope my friends provide interesting tips